# BMW X1 X Drive 2017

Tags: tires, bmw, x1, xdrive

Bought the car new on March 1st 2017 from local Strastone Dealer, Derby. Having done 14,000 miles there is excessive wear on the front tyres outer edges. They are Perelli P Zero 225/50 R18 99W ( Not Run Flats ) Tracking is OK. Check pressures weekly. Anyone have similar problems ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How hard do you drive your X1?

Answer (score 1):

Tracking (toe in/toe out) is checked quite easily but there are other components to Wheel Alignment that could affect the wear pattern on your tyres.  I would get the mechanics to check the following

1. Camber
2. Caster
3. Wear in bushes in wishbones
4. Worn/Broken springs
5. Correct Tyre size
6. Correct Wheel size

Also, check with BMW that you have the correct alignment figures.  its not unnkown for them to be changed to address issues like this that stem from the design of the components.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter what the tires are bud.. Flats run flats ctis- if excessive wear is noticed then something is seriously wrong wouldn't you agree? Even if you don't feel it in drive mode. Have your front alignment checked- if nothings wrong then the dealer either put the tires with the wear already on them just to sell the car or left them on there from wherever it was previously. Whatever the case is the tires should be changed out.